# Generic Quick sorting algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics

I am very new to this site and also a beginner programmer. I have been given a quick sort method which will sort an array of generic objects. I am using the in built compareTo method but when i come to call my method, it wont compile. The quicksort method takes an array of T items and an int left and int right. I do not know how to call on my method and when i do get it to work, my array doesnt become sorted. Can anyone give me any help at all? Im really struggling to understand and most sites on the internet are slightly to complex for my knowledge :( Heres the code:

```
    namespace QuickSort2
   {
    class Program
    {
     private void QuickSort<T>(T[] items, int left,  int right) where T: IComparable
     {
        int i, j;
        i = left; j = right;
        IComparable pivot = items[left];

        while (i <= j)
        {
            for (; (items[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0) && (i.CompareTo(right) < 0); i++); 
            for (; (pivot.CompareTo(items[j]) < 0) && (j.CompareTo(left) > 0); j--); 

             if (i <= j) 
            swap(ref items[i++], ref items[j--]); 

        } 
             if (left < j) QuickSort<T>(items, left,  j); 
             if (i < right) QuickSort<T>(items, i, right); 
    }
     static void swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
    {
      //swapcount++;
        T temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComparable[] array1 = { 3,5,7,8,1,2 };


        foreach (int s in array1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", s);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted version");
        foreach (int x in array1)
        {
            QuickSort(array1, 0, array1.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", x);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    }
   }
```

Comment: Are you doing this for learning purposes? Because if not, you can use [`List<T>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: "it wont compile": what is the error? and on which line?

Comment: You seem to never actually *call* your quick sort function. What is the error message?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I think the error would be on the `swap(ref items[...], ref items[...])`. As I recall, you can't ref individual array elements.

Comment: @SimonBelanger, yes, you can, and this QuickSort method actually works fine.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I should have checked. I mixed the `ref` restriction with properties.

Comment: I think it must be my method that is incorrect. Everything compiles, but it is not sorting my array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, <strike>but you're not actually calling the `QuickSort` method...</strike> *(EDIT: not true anymore after you edited your question...)*

```
QuickSort(array1, 0, array1.Length - 1);
```

You also need to make the `QuickSort` method static to be able to call it from the static method `Main`.

```
private static void QuickSort<T>(T[] items, int left,  int right) where T: IComparable
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include the call. I have called it the exct same way but it still does not work. The error is - An object reference is required for a none static field, method or property.

Comment: @user3480999, read my whole answer, it addresses this problem.

Comment: It still does not work :( It will not sort my integers in the correct order :( It has got to be something to do with : 

          while (i <= j)
            {
                for (; (items[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0) && (i.CompareTo(right) < 0); i++); 
                for (; (pivot.CompareTo(items[j]) > 0) && (j.CompareTo(left) > 0); j--); 
 
                 if (i <= j) 
                swap(ref items[i++], ref items[j--]); 
 
            } 
                 if (left < j) QuickSort<T>(items, left,  j); 
                 if (i < right) QuickSort<T>(items, i, right);